# Get-Content requires admin rights when run remotely

Tags: windows, powershell

I wish to open and process a text file on a remote Windows server using PowerShell.

We have something (roughly) like the following:

```
$path = "\\server1\c$\Users\gavin\Desktop\mylogfile.log"
Get-Content $path
```

Apparently, I can only get this to work when I have Admin rights to *server1*.

For security reasons, I cannot have unlimited access to all the servers I wish to access.

Is there a way of getting around this, given that I can only have less than full Admin rights?

I am thinking in terms of getting IT to alter my group privileges etc. on the remote machine(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\server1\C$` is a so-called [administrative share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share). They're hidden shares for administrator access to remote computers' filesystems. Accessing these requires admin privileges for security reasons.

Ask an administrator to create a dedicated share that allows you access, or (better yet) have the servers create the logs in a central location to which you have access.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I am completely new to Powershell and Windows admin, so please excuse the nature of the question.